# Как найти символ в переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Нужно чтобы программа находила символ в строке. Например:

```
i = 'apple'
if a in i:
    print(ошибка)
```

Но это сработает только если i станет a.
Как сделать так, чтобы можно было найти нужный символ в переменной, а не только полную переменную?

Comment: `Но это сработает только если i станет a.` - это не так. Это сработает, если в переменной a лежит одна буква из строки i или часть строки i.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, соответственно, нужно проитерироваться по буквам переменной:

```
word = 'apple'
var = 'cattle'
for ch in var:
    if ch in word:
        print(ch)
```

Но проще проверить есть ли в двух строках общие символы так:

```
if set(word) & set(var):
    print('есть пересечение')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 'apple'
if 'p' in i:
    print('ошибка')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно вашу букву обозначить буквой, а не переменной, т.е.:

```
word = 'apple'
if 'a' in word:
    print(ошибка)
```

Если нужно много букв проверить:

```
word = 'apple'
letters = 'abc'
for letter in letters:
    if letter in word:
        print(letter, 'in word.')
```

Comment: а если нужно много букв таким образом сделать? например 'a','b'? в этом все дело

Comment: @MiDem, если вы хотите чтобы вам ответили на этот вопрос, указывайте все детали в самом вопросе.

Comment: @MiDem, добавил, но в следующий раз лучше сразу указать, что именно вы хотите, как и сказал комментатор выше.